# react native route flux re-render component on stack pop

Tags: react-native

How do you re-run React Component Lifecycle methods to determine if a re-render is necessary when transitioning back to previous screens from stack using [React Native Router Flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)?
**Scenario:** Scene A -> B -> A
Lets say, A is the initial scene and we navigate from A to B with a **push i.e Actions.SceneB**. From B to A with a **Pop**. When the stack is popped to show Scene-A, none of the React Component methods are called for Scene-A. How do I determine if a re-render is necessary? I searched the Issues listed on the github repo and many seems to have this problem without a solution. How is this problem addressed?

I have the ugly work around of calling Actions.refresh() with a setTimeout.

**Work Around that works!**
This workaround seems to be hacky. There must be a better way to hook into component lifecycle to determine if a re-render is required. Perhaps a callback into the Component?

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#efefef' onPress={() => { Actions.pop(); setTimeout(()=> Actions.refresh(), 500)}} style={styles.cancel}>
```

**Options that do not work**

```
Actions.pop({type: 'reset'})

          OR

Actions.refresh({"key" : "sceneA"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work Around that works! This workaround seems to be hacky. There must be a better way to hook into component lifecycle to determine if a re-render is required.

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#efefef' onPress={() => { Actions.pop(); setTimeout(()=> Actions.refresh(), 500)}} style={styles.cancel}>
```

This will call `shouldComponentUpdate()` method which gives an option to determine, if a re-render is required.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue below code gave me required result.

```
let count = 0;
moveToMainScreen = () => {
    count += 1;
    Actions.pop({ refresh: { test: count } });
};



<Button onPress={this.moveToMainScreen}> Click </Button>
```