# Each time a Component is opened

Tags: react-native

Using Flux to naviagate from component to component is pretty easy. I've noticed however, on android if I hit the hardware back button, it'll go back to the previous component. Is there anyway for a component to be notified or run a function perhaps when it is being viewed?

The component isn't rerendered, and the component has already been mounted so WillMount and DidMount are not useful. Any ideas? Thanks so much..

Comment: Which navigator are you using ?

Comment: @sumanj React Native Router Flux

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available and many users logged issues for the similar requirements in GitHub project. No solution yet.
https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1510

I use a workaround as mentioned In [react native route flux re-render component on stack pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415183/react-native-route-flux-re-render-component-on-stack-pop)