# is it possible to tell when the View becomes "Available" in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm aware that there's `componentDidMount` that's called when the component is mounted, however in the case of React's `Navigator` it does not Unmount the root components when you move to another page. So, for example, if you wanted to refresh information when a page was loaded. How would you go about that?

For example, I'm on a `News` page and I tap to go to a article. I stay on the article for 15 minutes or so, during this time, new News was added. When I hit the back button and `pop` the current view, it pulls up the old view. (Does not remount it) How would I go about setting a trigger to reload the data.

I have some ideas for hacks, but want to know if there's a proper way to do it.

Comment: I had the same requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415183/react-native-route-flux-re-render-component-on-stack-pop

Answer (score 0):

The way I've been doing it is by creating a method that would refresh the information in News, then passing it to the next scene and calling it right before the navigator.pop().

Comment: It would be cool if the Navigator passed a command chain down for something like `componentDidBecomeActive`

Comment: They're currently working on a new Navigator that will fix a lot of the complaints, but yea it definitely needs a onFocus method built in...